# I am new to parsing and programming in general and I need help pulling a url and passing the page to beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python-3.4

Okay here is my code, i am using python 3.4.3 and beautifulsoup4:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import urllib

x=urllib.urlopen('https://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ:EA&ei=Byu9VYH3ApWlmAHXj5OYDA')

then I get back the following:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aedenny\Desktop\beautiful soup import.py", line 5, in 
    x=urllib.urlopen('https://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ:EA&ei=Byu9VYH3ApWlmAHXj5OYDA')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'

Answer (score 0):

The `urllib` module serves no purpose on its own, it only contains other modules, which you get by importing `urllib.module`

The function `urlopen` is inside `urllib.request`

```
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
```